# Android CalendarView for Showing Events

Tags: android, android-calendar, calendarview

I want to show a calendar with events using different colors on the date similar to default Calendar application. But I don't see any such API on the default calendar view.

Can anyone please direct me on right direction how to proceed with this? Should I extend default calendar and add my own functionality? Or should I use 5x5 text boxes with PageViewer and fragments?

Comment: Related/dupe: [Android calendar view](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3702998)

Comment: Related/dupe: [How to display a calendar UI in an Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6080307)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The built in CalendarView widget doesn't expose the ability to change the color of the calendar cells in month view. See [the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/widget/CalendarView.java#CalendarView.WeekView.drawWeekNumbersAndDates%28android.graphics.Canvas%29).

You might try the following approaches:

1. Extend from CalendarView and implement onDraw yourself. You'll have to reimplement all the existing drawing behavior, including these 4 methods:

   ```
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       drawBackground(canvas);
       drawWeekNumbersAndDates(canvas);
       drawWeekSeparators(canvas);
       drawSelectedDateVerticalBars(canvas);
   }
   ```
2. Implement you own CalendarView that allows customizing cells. I suggest [this project](https://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/source/browse/trunk/src/com/exina/android/calendar/CalendarView.java) as a good place to get started, since it already supports custom cells.

Comment: Other CalendarView-type library projects: [android-calendar-view](http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/), [Caldroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid)

Comment: Does anyone know any library that extend Android's `CalendarView` which allows easy customization for Date's cell drawable? I see many suggested libraries but they implement their own Calendar View which aren't extending from Android's `CalendarView`.

Comment: Currently there is no `onDraw` method.

Answer (score 14):

Last month I was able to implement a little calendar view using Caldroid https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid.

It's flexible to use and it's not so hard to get a custom calendar view as implementing `onDraw` from the `CalendarView`.

Check the view I created (just by following the documentation):

[image: Custom calendar view using Caldroid]

And of course you can go beyond that.

Answer (score 5):

I've written my own CalendarView much like the one seen in Google calendars aswell. Gives the ability to scroll between months, listeners, add events and is a gradle project: https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView. It uses paint to do all the drawing so it should easy to change to do anything you want.

Answer (score 4):

The following project is the best alternative I have seen so far to allow for displaying event-specific visuals in a date cell on the calendar:

https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView

Answer (score 0):

How about changing certain dates colour - by using 
android:dateTextAppearance and setDateTextAppearance(int)?
It was once described:
[change color of calendar dates android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937783/change-color-of-calendar-dates-android) 
You may try this out

Comment: I don't wanna change color of the cell. I want to draw a portion of the cell according to the time of each event.