# Customize CalendarView to allow individual days displayed differently

Tags: android, date, colors, calendarview

I have a calendar view and I want to customize individual days (say change color) under specific condition that I have. For example change the color of days if day is odd number or even number. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android CalendarView for Showing Events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556254/android-calendarview-for-showing-events)

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you can just modify android calender source code from here : https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar

As I know, if you use calenderview, you can just use it, not modify it