# CalendarView Out of Range Dates

Tags: android, calendarview

The default calendarView shows only the days between the minimum and maximum days inclusive if I set a minimum and maximum date. Is there any way to make all the days visible but have them be grayed out or do I have to create/use a separate calendarView in order to get that functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present, this can't be done.

See [Android CalendarView for Showing Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556254/android-calendarview-for-showing-events) and the numerous linked questions for similar problems.

You can either create your own custom CalendarView, or use an external library that provides more functionality.  The two popular ones look to be [**Caldroid**](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid) and [**android-calendar-view**](http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/).

Comment: That's rather unfortunate. Thanks!