# Disabling Fridays from a CalenderView

Tags: java, android, date, android-calendar

I am using a **CalenderView** in my app and i need to disable the selection of **Fridays** from it, and if possible need to show it as grey(not selectable)

```
<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/simpleCalendarView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CalendarView Out of Range Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801071/calendarview-out-of-range-dates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private Calendar lastSelectedCalendar = null;
private CalendarView calendarView;


calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
lastSelectedCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendarView.setMinDate(lastSelectedCalendar.getTimeInMillis() - 1000);
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    Calendar checkCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    checkCalendar.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
    if(checkCalendar.equals(lastSelectedCalendar))
        return;
    if(checkCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.FRIDAY)
        calendarView.setDate(lastSelectedCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
    else
        lastSelectedCalendar = checkCalendar;
}
});
```