# How to change the background color of the android calendar view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-calendar, calendarview

I am using the native calendar view present in android.I want to change the back ground colour of some of the dates present in the calendar view . I don't find any methods in the documentation . Can some one help me out ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556254/android-calendarview-for-showing-events

Answer (score 0):

you need to build your own CustomCalenderView

extends the Native CalendarView and build the behaviour that you want to color the background .

or you can use this library : [TimesSquare for Android](https://github.com/square/android-times-square)

and think it provide what you are looking for .

and please give me feedback .

Hope That Helps .

Comment: Thanks ...Do u have any which method I should override ??Are there any other alternate ways ?Do you know any other third party lib which allows the developer to change the background color of the particular dates in the calendar ??