# Add event to CalendarView

Tags: android, android-calendar, calendarview

I think the question says it all: is it possible to display events in the Android default `CalendarView`?

I know that it is made for widgets and not for a real Calendar application but my app should not be a Calendar application. It is only a little feature in my app so I think the View is perfect for my claims. I only can't view events in it, otherwise it is perfect for me.

I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16556857/2047987) and tried to overwrite the onDraw method from `CalenderView`:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    p = new Paint();

    p.setColor(Color.RED);
    p.setStrokeWidth(10);

    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100, p);
}
```

But even this code does not work and no rectangle is displayed. The other 4 methods are `private` so I can't overwrite them. Any other ideas how I can solve this problem? I do not want to use a library, but if there is no other way I'm looking for something what is really near to the stock `CalendarView`. Or maybe I can create a calendar file which is only visible in my app and not in other calendar apps?

Comment: What does your layout look like which contains the `CalendarView`?  Are you applying any custom resources to it?  Did you set the date for the view?

Comment: No I haven't tried custom resources or styles. I only have a normal layout with the calendarView

Comment: You'd need to show more code of how the view is being setup, added, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't add events in default `CalendarView`. either you need to make it custom or you need to use some library.

I have used [Caldroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid) library many times.it is easy to implement and robust.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Shameless plug. I've also written my own android CalendarView which allows you to add events, listeners, provides infinite scrolling and is a gradle project: https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView .