# Android Calendar API with Event

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am looking for way to get a calendar view with Event added on specific date something like the below:

[image]
And when I click on the calendar date another activity has to be opened?

Can the default calendar View help me doing the same or is there any other API that can help get the result like above?

Let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22000585/add-event-to-calendarview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use default calender library like

- [`CalendarView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html)

or you can use [Caldroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid)

Comment: I read somewhere we can't add event in Calendar view ... Can this possible? Do you have any example that can do something similar to my snapshot?

Comment: From Android 4.0(ICS) calender events are supported. see here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html . you can see lot of samples here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721963/how-to-add-calendar-events-in-android

Comment: The event is directly added Default Calendar app using Intent but not to CalendarView in the project. I want to add the numbers below each given date and show them in my app. Also all this when I open the project and show the calendarView. Can this be done directly using CalendarView?

Comment: try this sample http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2013/05/android-calendar-sync.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use default calendarview, I have used material calendarview for similar result.
You can even add events in text form as well as you can show drawable images with texts there.
See the line of code:

```
List<EventDay> events = new ArrayList<>();
events.add(new EventDay(calendar, CalendarUtils.getDrawableText(this, "₹"+wonAmt, Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD, R.color.green, 8)));
```