# How to change background color of the particular date in android?

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am using a Calender View in android.I am trying to change the background color of the particular date which i want. I have gone through the Calender View Document [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html)

But not able find a method like SetDateBackgroundColor(Date date,Color color);
Please tell me how to achieve it?

Comment: possible dublicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556254/android-calendarview-for-showing-events)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a method for that but you can set an `OnDateChangeListener` which checks for the current date selected and changes the background if the date matches your date.

Comment: No i  can't the listener it is not my requirement. I want mark the dates as soon as calender is loaded.