# How to highlight multiple dates in a android CalendarView programmatically

Tags: android, calendarview

I need to highlight several dates in a CalendaView. that should look like, [image]

I tried `setDate()`, but it didn't work as I want. Please help me to find a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android CalendarView for Showing Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556254/android-calendarview-for-showing-events)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Follow this link to get the library mCalendarView](https://github.com/SpongeBobSun/mCalendarView)

1. Use 3rd party library McalenderView.
2. Add to your gradle:

   `sun.bob:mcalendarview:1.0.0`

Try this code:

3. Some code:

```
calendarView = ((MCalendarView) view.findViewById(R.id.calendar_exp));

ArrayList<DateData> dates=new ArrayList<>();
dates.add(new DateData(2018,04,26));
dates.add(new DateData(2018,04,27));

for(int i=0;i<dates.size();i++) {
    //mark multiple dates with this code.
    calendarView.markDate(dates.get(i).getYear(),dates.get(i).getMonth(),dates.get(i).getDay()); 
}


Log.d("marked dates:-","" + calendarView.getMarkedDates()); //get all marked dates.
```

Comment: Did this solve your problem? please accept this answer.