# How to add an event to default calendar app in Android using Web-URL

Tags: android, html, deep-linking, android-calendar

How can I add an event to the native Android calendar app from web URL?

In IOS it's working fine with just linking to an ICS file. But in Android I couldn't find any solution!

I do NOT want to use Google calendar. I don't even want to just download the ics file.

Comment: Refer [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47450529/how-to-highlight-multiple-dates-in-a-android-calendarview-programmatically) may be this can resolve your query

Comment: Irrelevant. @TestProject

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tool that provides by Google for generating the URL which adds some calendar event into Android devices. Here is the link of the tool:

https://decomaan.github.io/google-calendar-link-generator/

Comment: It generates Google calendar's link and I already mentioned that I do NOT want to use it.