# Highlight multi selected dates in Calendar

Tags: android, android-studio

I wants to highlight multi-selected dates like absent(red color), present(green color) and holidays(blue color). I show many sites or github or stackoverflow answer but not find perfect solution.
Also set minimum and maximum dates to show calendar.

My question is like [this link example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47450529/how-to-highlight-multiple-dates-in-a-android-calendarview-programmatically) but no solution found.

Please help me to find perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Follow this link to get the library mCalendarView](https://github.com/SpongeBobSun/mCalendarView?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=2420)

1.Use 3rd party library McalenderView.

2.Add to your gradle:-

```
'sun.bob:mcalendarview:1.0.0'
```

Try this code:-

3.Some code:-

```
calendarView = ((MCalendarView) view.findViewById(R.id.calendar_exp));

    ArrayList<DateData> dates=new ArrayList<>();
    dates.add(new DateData(2018,04,26));
    dates.add(new DateData(2018,04,27));

    for(int i=0;i<dates.size();i++) {
        calendarView.markDate(dates.get(i).getYear(),dates.get(i).getMonth(),dates.get(i).getDay());//mark multiple dates with this code.
    }


    Log.d("marked dates:-",""+calendarView.getMarkedDates());//get all marked dates.
```

Comment: I already try this, this is good but i wants to multiple color also.

Answer (score 0):

Try out with these library :

```
dependencies {
implemantation 'com.savvi.datepicker:rangepicker:1.3.0'
}
```

Inside layout :

```
 <com.savvi.rangedatepicker.CalendarPickerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:tsquare_orientation_horizontal="false"
    app:tsquare_dividerColor="@color/transparent"
    app:tsquare_headerTextColor="@color/custom_header_text"
    />
```

Initialize it in Java Class

```
   calendar.init(lastYear.getTime(), nextYear.getTime()) //
            .inMode(CalendarPickerView.SelectionMode.RANGE)
            .withSelectedDate(new Date())
 // deactivates given dates, non selectable
            .withDeactivateDates(list)
 // highlight dates in red color, mean they are aleady used.
            .withHighlightedDates(arrayList)
// add subtitles to the dates pass a arrayList of SubTitle objects with date and text
            .withSubtitles(getSubtitle())
```

More : https://github.com/savvisingh/DateRangePicker

Comment: Bad view as my requirement :(

Answer (score 0):

change color by condition

```
if (res.type == "Type") {
calendarView.markDate(DateData(dateAsyear, dateAsMonth, dateAsDay).setMarkStyle(MarkStyle(MarkStyle.BACKGROUND, (ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(),R.color.YOURCOLOR)))))
}
```